# JDBCRealm can't find sqlite file

Tags: tomcat, sqlite

My authentication fails with

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such table: credentials
```

where credentials is the name of the user/password table.  I have checked the db file and the table is there.  I think you also get this error when sqlite jdbc can't even find the file.

I am specifying my realm in a META-INF/context.xml file.  Is there any trick to getting the path right?  I have tried just about everything I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You need your bean to be instantiated by something which knows how to handle the @Resrouce annotation. JSP itself doesn't know how.

In this case it would be simpler to locate the DataSource in the JNDI context:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/myDS");
```